# How to save binary image from json response to S3 bucket

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-s3, microsoft-graph-api, digital-ocean

I am trying to save a jpeg that I get back from [Microsoft's Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/profilephoto-get?view=graph-rest-1.0) to an S3 bucket (Digital Ocean Space actually but they work the same).  I am able to get the image binary from the graph api.  And can upload it successfully.  But the image is gibberish at the endpoint.  Here is the code I am using for reference.

```js
// Prep to fetch user photo from microsoft office 365
//     using recently aquired access token
const photoEndpoint = `${MS_GRAPH_URL}/v1.0/me/photo/$value`;
const config = { headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${access_token}` } };

// Fetch user photo from microsoft office 365
const { data: photo } = await axios.get(photoEndpoint, {
    headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${access_token}` }
});

await storeImage(photo, id);
```

where `storeImage` is defined as follows:

```js
// Import AWS SDK
const AWS = require("aws-sdk");

// Instantiate s3 instance to iterface with digital ocean spaced
const spacesEndpoint = new AWS.Endpoint("sfo2.digitaloceanspaces.com");
const s3 = new AWS.S3({
    endpoint: spacesEndpoint,
    accessKeyId: process.env.DO_SPACE_KEY,
    secretAccessKey: process.env.DO_SPACE_SECRET
});

const storeImage = (image, key) => {
    const params = {
        ACL: "public-read",
        Bucket: process.env.DO_SPACE_BUCKET,
        Key: `${key}`,
        Body: image,
        ContentType: "image/jpeg"
    };

    const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        s3.upload(params, (err, data) => {
            if (err) reject(err);

            resolve(data);
        });
    });

    return promise;
};
```

Any thoughts on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: might want to check that isBase64Encoded is false since you're not encoding the image, as far as I can tell here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where do you indicate the Content-Type of data you're requesting via your `axios` call?

The default appears to be `application/json` rather than `binary/octet-stream` so your image data will undergo unwanted transformation. ;)

Adding `responseType: 'stream'` to your axios request should fix your issue.

Comment: Awesome, this fixed it. Thanks for the help! :)